# Unity Android build error: GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog must be instantiated using the ScriptableObject.CreateInstance method

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I've been struggling with this issue for days. So my project was fine, and then suddenly making Android build started to fail (iOS build is still fine)

I build the project using command line (it's the project's requirement)

The build process doesn't stop or crash. It's just like pending forever.

The latest log is this:

```
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog must be instantiated using the ScriptableObject.CreateInstance method instead of new CommandLineDialog.
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/Scripting/StackTrace.cs:37)
UnityEngine.ScriptableObject:.ctor () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/Scripting/ScriptableObject.bindings.cs:19)
UnityEditor.EditorWindow:.ctor () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/EditorWindow.cs:1187)
GooglePlayServices.TextAreaDialog:.ctor () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/TextAreaDialog.cs:69)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:.ctor () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:168)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:CreateCommandLineDialog (string) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:189)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:GradleResolution (string,string,bool,bool,System.Action`1<System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Google.JarResolver.Dependency>>) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:365)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:DoResolutionUnsafe (string,bool,System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:928)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey7:<>m__0 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:819)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cHLLGXXRL4/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__1 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cHLLGXXRL4/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cHLLGXXRL4/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested (bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cHLLGXXRL4/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:TryExecuteAll () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.cHLLGXXRL4/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:500)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PollManualResetEvent (System.Threading.ManualResetEvent) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1624)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveSync (bool,bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1647)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:OnPostProcessScene () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Zw8JRhK8tU/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1201)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces/AttributeCallbackWrapper:OnProcessScene (UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:191)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces/<>c__DisplayClass17_0:<OnSceneProcess>b__1 (UnityEditor.Build.IProcessSceneWithReport) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:447)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces:InvokeCallbackInterfacesPair<UnityEditor.Build.IProcessScene, UnityEditor.Build.IProcessSceneWithReport> (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<UnityEditor.Build.IProcessScene>,System.Action`1<UnityEditor.Build.IProcessScene>,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<UnityEditor.Build.IProcessSceneWithReport>,System.Action`1<UnityEditor.Build.IProcessSceneWithReport>,bool) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:402)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces:OnSceneProcess (UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:445)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles (string,UnityEditor.BuildAssetBundleOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:571)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles (string,UnityEditor.BuildAssetBundleOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTarget) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:560)
```

I tried to find the method call GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog in my project but none was found. This method call might belong to some third party plugin libs or dependancies which are inaccessible.

I have no idea why things started to fail as no change was made since the last successful build.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Then I turn off "Enable Resolution On Build" In "Assets/External Denpendency Manager/Android Resolver/Settings". It works.
But why?
And I know this is not the final resolution.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't sound right. Turning that off might make the build process success but I'm afraid the build won't be functional at some places which involve external dependancies.

Comment: I think this is not the key point of error. Back up your project first to ensure that you can successfully build the Android project. The subsequent operations will rearrange the local Android dependency packages. Open Unity, Assets/External Denpendency Manager/Android Resolver/Force Reslove, normally it will stop and show success, but now it will not stop. I do not know why. If an SDK needs to be upgraded one day, Reslove must be executed. If the problem of not being able to stop can be solved, I believe the above problems will be solved. @Batman